# Spring integration MessagePublishingErrorHandler not being invoked

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am trying to publish my exceptions to a specific error channel.
I use a `MessagePublishingErrorHandler` for the same.

But my errors are not being routed to the channel I create.

Here is my code:-

channel:-

```
@Bean(value = "appErrorChannel")
    public PublishSubscribeChannel appErrorChannel() {
        return new PublishSubscribeChannel();
    }
```

MessageHandler:

```
@Bean
    public MessagePublishingErrorHandler myMessagePublishingErrorHandler(@Qualifier("appErrorChannel") PublishSubscribeChannel errChannel) {
        MessagePublishingErrorHandler messagePublishingErrorHandler = new MessagePublishingErrorHandler();
        messagePublishingErrorHandler.setDefaultErrorChannel(errChannel);
        return messagePublishingErrorHandler;
    }
```

FLow from this channel:-

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow errorFlow(@Qualifier("appErrorChannel") PublishSubscribeChannel errChannel) {
    return flow -> flow.channel(errChannel).
            publishSubscribeChannel(spec -> spec
                    .subscribe(f1 -> f1.handle(m -> System.out.println("******************* "+ m.getPayload()))));
}
```

My original channel. The `act` method throws an exception:-

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow pubSubFlow(PublishSubscribeChannel publishSubscribeChannel, 
                                      @Qualifier("myMessagePublishingErrorHandler")
            MessagePublishingErrorHandler messagePublishingErrorHandler) {
        return flow -> flow.channel(publishSubscribeChannel).split()
                .channel(new ExecutorSubscribableChannel(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)))
                .publishSubscribeChannel(config -> config
                .subscribe(f1 -> f1.handle("action", "act")
                        .handle(m1 -> {System.out.println(">>>"+m1);}))
                        .errorHandler(messagePublishingErrorHandler)
                );
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that `errorHandler` is used only with the `taskExecutor` in the `PublishSubscribeChannel`. Otherwise it is just ignored. We probably need to `WARN` on the matter in during `PublishSubscribeChannel` initialization. Feel free to raise a JIRA on the matter.

As a workaround you can do something like this:

```
.publishSubscribeChannel(new SyncTaskExecutor(), config -> config
```

This way you still in the same calling thread, but the `Runnable.run()` is going to be really wrapped to the `try...catch()` and an `ErrorMessage` is going to be published to your `appErrorChannel`.

Comment: I autowired an instance of TaskExecutor and it works, Thanks.